# getProduct() error with \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View

Tags: magento2

I would like to get the current product info and display to "app/design/frontend/Myproject/Myname/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml" by using getProduct() funciton of calss - \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View. However, it just showed "Magento Fatal Error: Call to member function getSku()"

app/code/Myproject/Myname/Block/Popup.php

```
<?php

 namespace Myproject\Myname\Block;

 class Popup extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View {

/**
 * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
 */
protected $productRepository;


public function getProduct123() {
        return $this->getProduct();
}
}
```

app/code/Myproject/Myname/view/frontend/templates/popup.phtml

```
<?php

/**
* @var \MyProject\Myname\Block\Popup $block
*/

$productName = $block->getProduct123()->getSku(); ?>

<div class="block-title">
  <strong>hihihi<?php  echo $productName; ?></strong>
</div>
```

app/design/frontend/Myproject/Myname/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
 <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="pop_up_2" 
          template="MyProject_Myname::popup.phtml"/>
 </referenceContainer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create layout catalog_product_view.xml :

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\View\Test" name="test"  template="Vendor_Module::account/test.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Create block and extend it with view like below :

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\View;

use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;

class Test extends View
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Url\EncoderInterface $urlEncoder
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $productHelper
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductTypes\ConfigInterface $productTypeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface $localeFormat
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     * @param ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Url\EncoderInterface $urlEncoder,
        \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $productHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductTypes\ConfigInterface $productTypeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface $localeFormat,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $urlEncoder, $jsonEncoder, $string, $productHelper, $productTypeConfig, $localeFormat, $customerSession, $productRepository, $priceCurrency, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getProductData()
    {
        $product = $this->getProduct();
        if($product) {
            return $product;
        }
        return [];
    }
}
```

And call this function in phtml using $block like below.
create test.phtml :

```
<?php
/** @var Vendor\Module\Block\View\Test $block */
$productData = $block->getProductData();
$productSku = $productData->getSku();
```

Comment: After extend \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View this block , use registry is not proper way , if you use registry , the main think of view block is lost

Answer (score 1):

Please update the code in app/design/frontend/Myproject/Myname/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml to consider your custom block in phtml template.

**From**

```
 <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="pop_up_2" 
          template="MyProject_Myname::popup.phtml"/>
 </referenceContainer>
```

**to**

```
 <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Myproject\Myname\Block\Popup" name="pop_up_2" 
          template="MyProject_Myname::popup.phtml"/>
 </referenceContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your `app/code/Myproject/Myname/Block/Popup.php` with below code

And change name of file from **Showproduct.php** to **Popup.php**

```
<?php

namespace Myproject\Myname\Block;

class Popup extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View {

    public $registry;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Registry $registry)
    {
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    public function getProduct123() {
        $product = $this->registry->registry('current_product');
        return $product;
    }
}
```

And replace the code with below code for file `app/design/frontend/Myproject/Myname/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`

```
 <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Myproject\Myname\Block\Popup" name="pop_up_2" 
          template="MyProject_Myname::popup.phtml"/>
 </referenceContainer>
```